# How do I update multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried with this but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE TEAM 
SET NAME = 'A' 
SET DESCRIPTION = 'a' 
SET COD_BRAND = 'a' 
SET COD_EMPLOYEE = 'a' 
SET PRICE = 'a' 
SET DATE = 'a' 
WHERE COD_TEAM = 'E01';
```

Comment: What about the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is unclear? And you are updating multiple *columns* not *rows* in your example?

Comment: @Programmer01 . . . `UPDATE` has only one `SET` clause, with expressions separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

The target columns in the `SET` clause should be comma separated, and `SET` only should appear once:

```sql
UPDATE TEAM
SET NAME = 'A', DESCRIPTION = 'a', COD_BRAND = 'a', COD_EMPLOYEE = 'a',
    PRICE = 'a', DATE = 'a'
WHERE COD_TEAM = 'E01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong ,try like below

```
UPDATE TEAM 
SET NAME = 'A',
    DESCRIPTION = 'a',
    COD_BRAND = 'a', 
    COD_EMPLOYEE = 'a', 
    PRICE = 'a',
    DATE = 'a' 
WHERE COD_TEAM = 'E01';
```